# ¿Como agregar el UV de manera correcta para el paquete de ipyvolume en python, para visualizar la textura y el objeto 3d de manera correcta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import ipyvolume.pylab as p3

region = np.s_[10:-10, 10:-10]
x, y, z = x[region], y[region], z[region]
p3.figure()
p3.plot_mesh(x, y, z, wireframe=False)
p3.show()
```

Resutado:

[image: Sin la textura]

Intento colocarle la textura por eso agrego atributos a la función plot_mesh:

```
textura=PIL.Image.open(ruta+"/colab/"+nombre+".png")
u=x
v=y
p3.plot_mesh(x, y, z,u=u,v=v,texture=textura, wireframe=False)
p3.show()
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado agregando textura]

Intuyo que el error es por que no he agregado el UV correcto ya que le asignado el x, y respectivo, **¿Como podria aisgnarle el UV correcto ?**

Gracias de antemano